# How can my ANTLR lexer match a token made of characters that are subset of another kind of token?

Tags: antlr, grammar

I have what I think is a simple ANTLR question.  I have two token types: `ident` and `special_ident`.  I want my `special_ident` to match a single letter followed by a single digit.  I want the generic `ident` to match a single letter, optionally followed by any number of letters or digits.  My (incorrect) grammar is below:

```
expr 
    : special_ident
    | ident
    ;

special_ident : LETTER DIGIT;
ident         : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)*;

LETTER : 'A'..'Z';
DIGIT  : '0'..'9';
```

When I try to check this grammar, I get this warning:

> Decision can match input such as "LETTER DIGIT" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2.
>   As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input

I understand that my grammar is ambiguous and that input such as `A1` could match either `ident` or `special_ident`.  I really just want the `special_ident` to be used in the narrowest of cases.

Here's some sample input and what I'd like it to match:

```
A      : ident
A1     : special_ident
A1A    : ident
A12    : ident
AA1    : ident
```

How can I form my grammar such that I correctly identify my two types of identifiers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on Carl's thought, I would guess you have four different cases:

1. A
2. AN
3. AA(A|N)*
4. AN(A|N)+

Only option 2 should be token special_ident and the other three should be ident.  All tokens can be identified by syntax alone.  Here is a quick grammar I was able to test in ANTLRWorks and it appeared to work properly for me.  I think Carl's might have one bug when trying to check AA , but getting you 99% there is a huge benefit, so this is only a minor modification to his quick thought.

```
prog 
    :    (expr WS)+ EOF;

expr 
    : special_ident {System.out.println("Found special_ident:" + $special_ident.text + "\n");}
    | ident {System.out.println("Found ident:" + $ident.text + "\n");}
    ;

special_ident : LETTER DIGIT;

ident         : LETTER 
    |LETTER DIGIT (LETTER|DIGIT)+
    |LETTER LETTER (LETTER|DIGIT)*;

LETTER : 'A'..'Z';
DIGIT  : '0'..'9';
WS 
    :   (' '|'\t'|'\n'|'\r')+;
```

Comment: Thanks...  I think this is all making more sense. is the last option in `ident` redundant?  Wouldn't `LETTER LETTER` make the whole rule be equivalent?  Also, would it be equivalent for the entire rule to say `LETTER LETTER? | LETTER DIGIT (LETTER|DIGIT)+`?

Comment: There are several different ways you can have the rules (I think), I was just making sure the LETTER DIGIT has another letter or digit after to separate it from the special_ident rule.  The LETTER LETTER option does not require any more tokens after.  That is why one has a plus sign and the other has the asterisk.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that you have 3 cases:

- `A`
- `AN`
- `A(A|N)(A|N)+`

You could classify the middle one as `special_ident` and the other two as `ident`; seems that should do the trick.

I'm a bit rusty with ANTLR, I hope this hint is enough. I can try to write out the expressions for you but they could be wrong:

```
long_ident    : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT) (LETTER | DIGIT)+
special_ident : LETTER DIGIT;
ident         : LETTER | long_ident;
```